# Numpy - Impossible to perform a matricial product with 3 matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have the 3 following matrix :

```
      matrix1 = np.array(eval(der_input_LU[j]));
      submatrix1 = matrix1[0:100][0:4]
      matrix2 = invCrossMatrix
      matrix3 = np.array(eval(der_input_LU[l]));
      submatrix3 = matrix3[0:4][0:100];
```

with the shape of each one :

```
      print 'shape matrix1 = ', submatrix1.shape
      print 'shape matrix2 = ', matrix2.shape
      print 'shape matrix3 = ', submatrix3.shape
```

which prints :

```
shape submatrix1 =  (4, 100)
shape matrix2 =  (4, 4)
shape submatrix3 =  (4, 100)
```

I am looking for doing matricial product between these 3 matrices. I tried to use `np.linalg.multi_dot` like this :

```
matFinal = np.linalg.multi_dot([submatrix1,matrix2,submatrix3])
```

But I get the following error :

```
invCrossMatrix =  [[ 2.76704670e-09  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  6.82633333e-06 -1.65769406e-19 -2.12753150e-12]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -1.65769406e-19  6.82633333e-06 -3.31538864e-19]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -2.12753150e-12 -3.31538864e-19  1.36526667e-05]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program1.py", line 1497, in <module>
    map(integ_LU_cross, g_LU(i))
  File "program1.py", line 1436, in integ_LU_cross
    function_A = aux_fun_LU_cross(way, ecs, I1[0], I1[1], I1[2])
  File "program1.py", line 1369, in aux_fun_LU_cross
    submatrix3 = matrix3[0:4][0:100];          
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

As you can see, I tried to respect the order : `(100,4)*(4,4)*(4,100)` but it doesn't work.

Do I respect the right dimensions in order to use `multi_dot` function ?
I can't find where my error could come from.

Comment: If the program prints `shape submatrix3 =  (4, 100)` then `submatrix3` has been successfully defined. How is it that you are getting an error saying `submatrix3 = matrix3[0:4][0:100]` raises `IndexError: too many indices for array`?

Comment: @unutbu . I think the error comes from sometimes in the code, the matrix3 is equal to `()`, so it produces error when I try to multiply it by matrix1 or matrix2 : Is there a way to build a matrix from this `()`value ? then, I could circumvent this error of :  `IndexError: too many indices for array`?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are trying to compute before we can suggest a satisfying solution.